# Is it correct to say "I very seldom do something"? How to emphasize "seldom" or "rarely"

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say "I very seldom do something"?

It sounds strange to me.

How to emphasize "seldom" or "rarely"?

Comment: "I very seldom do something" sounds perfectly normal to this US English speaker, except maybe for the fact that we say "rarely" more often than "seldom".  *Very* is a perfectly correct way to emphasize it.

Comment: *Very rarely* and *very seldom* are both idiomatic (in BrE) and the former is the more common.

Comment: What @Mick, stangdon said - per [this NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+seldom+do%2CI+rarely+do&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20seldom%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20rarely%20do%3B%2Cc0) ***rarely*** has become more common everywhere in recent decades, but this relatively recent usage switch is far more marked in AmE,

Comment: "I seldom do" sounds more natural; accentuating it seems redundant.

Comment: @Mick I (UK NW) find 'very seldom' jarring. [Google 2-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+rarely%2Cvery+seldom&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) show the ratio of current tokens for  'very seldom' to 'very rarely' to be about 1 : 4 in 'BrE'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the right answer is to say:

> I hardly ever do something

It looks more clearer and formal, the only thing I am not sure enough about is you want to emphasize that would be not academically correct, you may say for example I do hardly ever, for example, waste my time watching TV and so on.

Comment: This is a good comment, but doesn't actually address the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentences are fine, but if you want variety there are many expressions that are synonymous with "seldom" which you can swap in.  Some are idiomatic, and they all represent varying degrees of frequency.

> He rarely plays football
>
> He plays football, but only once in a while
>
> She likes to play piano once in a blue moon
>
> She occasionally plays the piano
>
> They don't go to the movies very often
>
> They go to the movies every now and then
>
> I hardly ever speak Japanese these days
>
> I speak Japanese these days, but only on and off.
>
> My roommate scarcely ever washes the dishes
>
> My roommate washes the dishes from time to time
>
> He visits only very infrequently
>
> His visits are few and far between.

Then there are various other idiomatic expressions which *imply* infrequency, but also refer to other factors (like mood, situation, etc.)

> I do it when I feel like it
>
> I do it when the time is right
>
> I do it when the mood hits me
>
> I do it when the stars are aligned

And others.

Answer (score -2):

**I very seldom do say** things like that.

**I very rarely do speak** to them.

**He very rarely does play** football.

This is called using emphatic helping verb. It can be used in the simple past too:

**They rarely did use** sugar in their recipe.

I have explained the EMPHATIC usage here. For REGULAR usage, just remove the helping verb.

Comment: This is incorrect. You should not be using *do*.

Comment: As @Mick says, unless the specific context calls for an exception for some reason, those first three would be better as: _He very rarely plays football; I very rarely speak to them; I very rarely say things like that_.

Comment: There is such a thing as emphatic use of the verb and it could be used here. I am NOT SAYING that //He very rarely play football// is not right. I am saying that: He very rarely DOES play football is a particular USAGE called emphatic usage.

Comment: @Lambie: I think the only natural context for, say, *He rarely does play football* requires stress on ***does***. And it's not just *emphasis* in the general sense - it only really works in contexts where it's effectively in ***refutation*** of a preceding assertion (or strong implication) that he plays football (with unspecified frequency, so the refutation is intended to deny that he does so often enough for this to be important).

Comment: Lambie - You've taken the O.P.'s original sentence, and replaced the "something" with a verb and object. Instead, the verb should replace "does", and the object should replace "something". As @Fumble mentions, this (the emphatic usage with _rarely_ or _seldom_) would be quite unusual – you'd generally find the emphatic usage the other way around; i.e.: **Ted**: _He hardly ever plays football_. **Ned**: _No, he does play football  –  all the time!_

Comment: @Lambie this doesn't feel natural to me either.  I'm fine with the helping verb but I would place the adverb after "do/does", or even at the end of the sentence.  "I do, rarely, play football."  "She does speak to them, but very rarely."

Comment: Sorry, you guys are wrong. All the sentences I gave are examples of using the emphatic helping verb ALONG with seldom and rarely and they are 100% grammatical. Of course,/ He rarely does play football/ automatically means the does is stressed! That's the whole point!

Comment: @Lambie: J.R.'s example context doesn't reflect the "stressed ***do*** + ***rarely***" combination I had in mind, which would be something like **Ted:** *He always gets blind drunk after playing football.* **Ned:** *But he very rarely **does** play football, so that's hardly a problem.* The "emphasis" there is on whether or not he plays *at all*, not whether he does so *rarely*.

Comment: What difference does any of this make? You are downvoting an explanation that an advanced speaker of English might very well like....so...

Comment: @Lambie - Rightfully downvoted, then. Our community caters to the learner. At the very least, you should expand your answer, and explain why this wouldn't be heard very often. All you've done here is post three very non-idiomatic sentences and provided a proper name for the construct. I don't see how that helps the leaner community very much.

Comment: No, my examples are most definitely not non-idiomatic. Who cares whether something is "heard" often or not? It is not a construct. It is an emphatic form used in English. It helps advanced learners a lot. Frankly, I find you to be mean spirited.

Comment: @Lambie: I didn't downvote, but I agree wholeheartedly with what J.R. says above. The *only* context in which your examples would normally occur is relatively unusual (if not *contrived*), so it wouldn't normally be helpful to learners. And it would be potentially counterproductive if they just assumed the "emphasis" simply applied to the statement itself, rather than refutation of some preceding or implicit assertion.